# curl and create image

Tags: php, image, curl

I have this part of the script. Before this script, I have a curl function that is returning a page's content. Using preg_match, I am getting these values. The problem is with the imagecreate script or something related to that.

Here is the script:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $user = "username"; 
    $pw = "pass"; 
    $ne_ki = 1;
    $postfields = "name=".$id."&pass=".$pw."&ne_ki=".$ne_ki; 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // Get the header 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://domain.tld/login.php"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'C:\AppServ\www\curl\cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://domain.tld/profile.php?id='.$_GET['id']);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $data2 = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    preg_match_all ("/<div class=\"profil_jobb_masodik2\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/", $data2,$matches);
    preg_match_all ("/<div class=\"lista_mini_fej\">([^`]*?)<\/div>/", $data2, $matches2);
    preg_match_all ("/<nobr>([^`]*?)<\/nobr>/", $data2, $matches3);
    $string = preg_match("/\([0-9]+\)/", $matches2[0][0], $strend);
    $HTML = '';
    $HTML .= "DATA1: ".$matches3[0][0]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA2: ".$matches[1][0]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA3: ".$matches[1][1]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA4: ".$matches[1][2]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA5: ".$matches[1][3]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA6: ".$matches[1][4]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA7: ".$matches[1][5]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA8: ".$matches[1][6]."<br />";
    $HTML .= "DATA9: ".$matches[1][7]."<br />";
    if (!empty($strend[0]))
    $HTML .= "DATA10: ".$strend[0]."<br />";
     $text = $HTML;
    if(empty($text))

        fatal_error('Error: Text not properly formatted.') ;



    // customizable variables

    $font_file      = 'ambient.ttf';

    $font_size      = 23 ; // font size in pts

    $font_color     = '#ffffff' ;

    $image_file     = 'bb.jpeg';



    // x and y for the bottom right of the text

    // so it expands like right aligned text

    $x_finalpos     = 227;

    $y_finalpos     = 103;





    // trust me for now...in PNG out PNG

    $mime_type          = 'image/png' ;

    $extension          = '.png' ;

    $s_end_buffer_size  = 4096 ;



    // check for GD support

    if(!function_exists('ImageCreate'))

        fatal_error('Error: Server does not support PHP image generation') ;



    // check font availability;

    if(!is_readable($font_file)) {

        fatal_error('Error: The server is missing the specified font.') ;

    }



    // create and measure the text

    $font_rgb = hex_to_rgb($font_color) ;

    $box = @ImageTTFBBox($font_size,0,$font_file,$text) ;



    $text_width = abs($box[2]-$box[0]);

    $text_height = abs($box[5]-$box[3]);



    $image =  imagecreatefrompng($image_file);



    if(!$image || !$box)

    {

        fatal_error('Error: The server could not create this image.') ;

    }



    // allocate colors and measure final text position

    $font_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,$font_rgb['red'],$font_rgb['green'],$font_rgb['blue']) ;



    $image_width = imagesx($image);



    $put_text_x = $image_width - $text_width - ($image_width - $x_finalpos);

    $put_text_y = $y_finalpos;



    // Write the text

    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $put_text_x,  $put_text_y, $font_color, $font_file, $text);





    header('Content-type: ' . $mime_type) ;

    ImagePNG($image) ;



    ImageDestroy($image) ;

    exit ;





    /*

        attempt to create an image containing the error message given. 

        if this works, the image is sent to the browser. if not, an error

        is logged, and passed back to the browser as a 500 code instead.

    */

    function fatal_error($message)

    {

        // send an image

        if(function_exists('ImageCreate'))

        {

            $width = ImageFontWidth(5) * strlen($message) + 10 ;

            $height = ImageFontHeight(5) + 10 ;

            if($image = ImageCreate($width,$height))

            {
                $background = ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255) ;

                $text_color = ImageColorAllocate($image,0,0,0) ;

                ImageString($image,5,5,5,$message,$text_color) ;    

                header('Content-type: image/png') ;

                ImagePNG($image) ;

                ImageDestroy($image) ;
                // This is line 197
                exit ;

            }

        }





    }





    /* 

        decode an HTML hex-code into an array of R,G, and B values.

        accepts these formats: (case insensitive) #ffffff, ffffff, #fff, fff 

    */    

    function hex_to_rgb($hex) {

        // remove '#'

        if(substr($hex,0,1) == '#')

            $hex = substr($hex,1) ;



        // expand short form ('fff') color to long form ('ffffff')

        if(strlen($hex) == 3) {

            $hex = substr($hex,0,1) . substr($hex,0,1) .

                   substr($hex,1,1) . substr($hex,1,1) .

                   substr($hex,2,1) . substr($hex,2,1) ;

        }



        if(strlen($hex) != 6)

            fatal_error('Error: Invalid color "'.$hex.'"') ;



        // convert from hexidecimal number systems

        $rgb['red'] = hexdec(substr($hex,0,2)) ;

        $rgb['green'] = hexdec(substr($hex,2,2)) ;

        $rgb['blue'] = hexdec(substr($hex,4,2)) ;



        return $rgb ;

    }

?>
```

Line 197 is marked with a comment. The error is:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\curl\index.php:1) in C:\AppServ\www\curl\index.php on line 197

What is the problem?

Comment: you're sending something to browser before the created image get sends to browser. So the image can not be rendered properly. Maybe it is simply a ``BOM`` (byte order mark)... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: yes i have read that if something is sent to the browser then it is writing this error message but i have there the script could you please tell me what is it?
--------
UPdate: Thanks to thedom, i have found the solution i have saved my php file using UTF-8 in notepad++ and now i tried it with the UTF-8 without BOM and now it is printing the image :) thanks @thedom

Comment: as I mentioned in my previous post - it ___might___ be a byte order mark. Check the encoding of your file. __EDIT:__ e.g. notepad puts a byte order mark in front of the file when saving it as UTF-8...